# XML databinding to TreeView (or Tab control), bind attribute based on different attribute

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, treeview, tabcontrol

I have some xml:

```
<Test>
  <thing location="home" status="good"/>
  <thing location="work" status="bad"/>
  <thing location="mountains" status="good"/>
</Test>
```

The leaves on the `TreeView` are the values of the status attribute; the nodes will be the value of the location attribute.

├──bad
│.....└──work
└──good
.......├──home
.......└──mountains

Currently, I populate the `TreeView` (or `TabControl`) manually, iterating through the xml, adding the nodes to the appropriate leaf.
Can this be done via databinding?  I'm guessing a Converter will be involved...
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going to bind to an XmlDataSource you could use a TransformFile with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/Test">
    <Test>
      <good>
        <xsl:for-each select="thing[@status='good']">
           <xsl:element name="{@location}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </good>
      <bad>
        <xsl:for-each select="thing[@status='bad']">
          <xsl:element name="{@location}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </bad>
    </Test>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Add an `XPath="/Test/*"` property to the XmlDataSource to remove the "Test" root element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's very helpful.
I suspect I need DataTemplates in the xaml for the TreeView and TabControl items?

Comment: You may not need DataTemplates, but my knowledge of WPF is limited. Try DataBinding without and see how it looks. The ASP.NET TreeView works if you just DataBind the XmlDataSource. I stupidly assumed your question was about an ASP.NET TreeView (you need a "wpf" tag on your question.)